Error: Authentication kind "jwt" configured, but no XSUAA instance bound to application
I would like to connect my BTP CAP Node.js app to external SAP service in production env using destinations. It is important to use OAuth2.0ClientCredentials authentication method. Sandbox works for me. Official document is bit confusing.
When I run production profile, I am getting below error. Do I need any additional NPM package, or require additional configuration in package.json or elsewhere?
What to do in order to successfully fetch data from "production" environment?    Thank you.

package.json
  "cds": {
    "requires": {
      "Some_ExternalServiceV4": {
        "kind": "odata",
        "model": "srv/external/Some_ExternalServiceV4",
        "[sandbox]": {
          "credentials": {
            "url": "https://sandbox.api.sap.com/sappricing/datafetch"
          }
        },
        "[production]": {
          "credentials": {
            "destination": "datafetch-destination"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

